# How to set up SandBox In-App Purchase in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, sandbox

I integrated the In-App purchase for my app. I also set the purchase on itunes & shows me status as `Ready to Submit`.

But I want to test it without submitting the binary.

So, Is there is another set required for Sandbox In-App testing?

My code:

```
    [[SubclassInAppHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {
        if (success)
        {
            [appDel dismissGlobalHUD];
            NSMutableArray *arrProductsBuyHeart = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            NSMutableArray *arrTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            for (SKProduct *Sss in products)
            {
                NSString *string = Sss.productIdentifier;//@"hello bla bla";
                if ([string rangeOfString:@"com.xxxxxxxx.buy"].location == NSNotFound) {
                    //NSLog(@"string does not contain Buy");
                } else {
                    NSMutableDictionary *dictprod = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                    [dictprod setObject:Sss.productIdentifier forKey:@"ProductIdentifier"];
                    [dictprod setObject:Sss.price forKey:@"ProductPrice"];
                    [dictprod setObject:Sss.localizedTitle forKey:@"ProductTitle"];
                    [arrTemp addObject:dictprod];
                }
            }
            if (arrTemp.count > 0)
            {
                NSSortDescriptor *brandDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"ProductPrice" ascending:YES];
                NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:brandDescriptor];
                arrProductsBuyHeart = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[arrTemp sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors]];
                //NSLog(@"My products > %@",arrProductsBuyHeart);
                for (int i = 0;i<[arrProductsBuyHeart count];i++)
                {
                    NSString *strProductID = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrProductsBuyHeart objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ProductIdentifier"]]RemoveNull];
                    NSString *strPrice = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",[[arrProductsBuyHeart objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ProductPrice"]]RemoveNull];
                    if ([strProductID isEqualToString:InApp200Coins])
                    {
                        [btn1KHeart setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strPrice] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    }
                    else if ([strProductID isEqualToString:InApp600Coins])
                    {
                        [btn2KHeart setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strPrice] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    }
                    else if ([strProductID isEqualToString:InApp900Coins])
                    {
                        [btn4KHeart setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strPrice] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    }
                    else if ([strProductID isEqualToString:InApp2KCoins])
                    {
                        [btn10KHeart setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strPrice] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    }
                    else if ([strProductID isEqualToString:InApp4KCoins])
                    {
                        [btn50KHeart setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strPrice] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                DisplayAlertWithTitle(@"Error Message", @"Unable to get product list or no in-app purchase found.");
        }
        else
        {
            [appDel dismissGlobalHUD];
            DisplayAlertWithTitle(@"Error Message", @"Unable to get product list or no in-app purchase found.");
        }
    }];
}
```

**Output** DisplayAlertWithTitle(@"Error Message", @"Unable to get product list or no in-app purchase found."); & **Not able to get Product List.**

**Help me to solve this**.

Answer (score 3):

First of you can create app in itunes connect.

-add product in In-app purchase.

-then after itunes home page you can add test user click on manage user.

[image]

after add you can remove your apple account in your device then login with test user

after login you can test in-App purchase in Sandbox mode.

Comment: No, you can test in you device.

Comment: ok.Thanks a lot for your Answer! let me check after some time & call you back if any issue,otherwise accept as an answer.

Comment: it will work on ios6 simulator. But will a little slow in responses.

Comment: it's network issue. while you can click to buy it fetch your product details from server. so it take few time.

Comment: Starting from iOS7 it is impossible to test In-Apps in simulator (:

Answer (score 0):

Create a test user account in iTunes Connect, as described in “Creating Test User Accounts” in [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/About.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225).

On a development iOS device, sign out of the App Store in Settings. Then build and run your app from Xcode.

On a development OS X device, sign out of the Mac App Store. Then build your app in Xcode and launch it from the Finder.

Use your app to make an in-app purchase. When prompted to sign in to the App Store, use your test account. Note that the text **“[Environment: Sandbox]”** appears as part of the prompt, indicating that you’re connected to the test environment.

**If the text “[Environment: Sandbox]” doesn’t appear, you’re using the production environment. Make sure you’re running a development-signed build of your app. Production-signed builds use the production environment.**

**Important:** Don’t use your test user account to sign in to the production environment. If you do, the test user account becomes invalid and can no longer be used.